Adjust Buttons and Labels font sizes when default font size of the device increased or decreased
I realized buttons and labels font sizes of Codename One app doesn't change when the font size of the device is adjusted.
I tried this in Android and iOS device.
How can the font sizes of buttons and labels change dynamically as the default font size of the phone is increased or decreased?

I've never worked with Codename One, that's why I'm leaving a comment instead of an answer. I've been styling widgets on the web a lot, and your question just caught my eye. So if there's any chance for you to use CSS, you may try adding something like button, label { font: inherit } — this might help because such elements have their basic styling, at least in browsers. Not sure about labels though, but buttons for sure.

Yes I am styling using CSS. Attribute font: inherit  enables font sizes of both buttons and labels to change as font size of the phone is adjusted. The problem now is that the attribute font: inherit overrides all font attributes like font-family and font-size

Sorry, I didn't mention that every property could be specified separately, font: inherit is just a shorthand. So you may use font-size: inherit :)

Okay, what if I want to use a custom font-family other than the default font-family of the phone?

I suppose you just specify whatever font-family you want, these properties don't affect each other. But it holds true for web development, not sure about your case — although I believe it's worth trying.

I tried and font: inherit override all other style attributes including font-family, background-color, border-radius etc. All other custom attributes don't work when font: inherit is set

This is work that's part of our accessibility support that was never implemented. I believe even system fonts and the definitions of small, medium and large don't change when the system fonts change.
I believe this is the code that does it for Android, it should consider the size of the device font too. Unfortunately, that would break compatibility to many apps so it was never implemented.

I also realized when display size in settings of the phone (Android 10) is increased/decreased apps icons, labels and font sizes of labels and buttons also increase/decrease in all apps including Codename One apps. Can display size be adopted to font size in Codename One apps?

I noted in Android the font sizes of the following change as the phone's font size change: Webpage in BrowserComponent,  DatePicker,  TimePicker, StringPicker eg this demo. Can pickers' ability to change font sizes be adopted to labels and buttons?

Display size = Resolution. So it means the device returns different width/height and behaves seamlessly. Font size is a different beast. These are all native OS components which have advantages and disadvantages. Notice these components aren't impacted by CSS and you have limited control over them.

I figured a way to achieve this dynamically using Style & Font. Font size options (small, default, medium & large) can be in app Settings where the selected option can be saved to Preferences. Then when a form is being created, all components (TextFields, Labels, Buttons) can be added to a Component array. After a form show, changeFontSizes function can be called to change the font of all Components. That is
private void createUI() {
    Form form = new Form("Font Size Setting", BoxLayout.y());
    ArrayList<Component> cmpArr = new ArrayList<>();

    Container cntFontSizes = new Container(new GridLayout(1, 4));
    Button btnSmallFont = new Button("Small", "btnFontSize");
    Button btnDefaultFont = new Button("Default", "btnFontSize");
    Button btnMediumFont = new Button("Medium", "btnFontSize");
    Button btnLargeFont = new Button("Large", "btnFontSize");

    TextField textField = new TextField();
    textField.setUIID("tf");
    cmpArr.add(textField);

    Button btn = new Button("Button", "btn");
    cmpArr.add(btn);

    Label lbl = new Label("Label", "lbl");
    cmpArr.add(lbl);

    btnSmallFont.addActionListener(e -> {
        Preferences.set("FontSize", "small");
        changeFontSizes(cmpArr);
    });
    btnDefaultFont.addActionListener(e -> {
        Preferences.set("FontSize", "default");
        changeFontSizes(cmpArr);
    });
    btnMediumFont.addActionListener(e -> {
        Preferences.set("FontSize", "medium");
        changeFontSizes(cmpArr);
    });
    btnLargeFont.addActionListener(e -> {
        Preferences.set("FontSize", "large");
        changeFontSizes(cmpArr);
    });
    cntFontSizes.addAll(btnSmallFont, btnDefaultFont, btnMediumFont, btnLargeFont);

    form.addAll(cntFontSizes, textField, btn, lbl);
    form.show();

    //show default font size
    Preferences.set("FontSize", "default");
    changeFontSizes(cmpArr);
}

public void changeFontSizes(ArrayList<Component> cmpArr) {
    float size = 0;
    switch (Preferences.get("FontSize", null)) {
        case "small":
            size = 2f;
            break;
        case "default":
            size = 3.5f;
            break;
        case "medium":
            size = 3.8f;
            break;
        case "large":
            size = 4f;
            break;
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < cmpArr.size(); c++) {
        Style style = cmpArr.get(c).getAllStyles();
        Font font = Font.createTrueTypeFont("poppins_medium.ttf", "poppins_medium.ttf")
                .derive(CN.convertToPixels(size), Font.STYLE_PLAIN);
        style.setFont(font);
    }
}

